# How to use a vector mockup with perspective?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, mockup, perspective

I don't know how to explain what do I want, so I put some images to explain that.

[image: Vector Mockup]

We have a `vector mockup` here for example (image 1).
There is no problem with this mockup because you need just put the image or vector between some layers ...but if you have a vector mockup with `perspective` then what would you do?

[image]

Photoshop had a solution for this: `Smart Object`
but what about the Illustrator?
Every time we need to transfer or fix the alignment to make a right perspective?
I'm looking for the best and fast way ...

Comment: You can always use Transform...there are other ways too but I don't have the time to give an answer now, it you don't get an answer by the time I get back home I'll give you some guidelines.

Comment: @Alin I know that ... but it waste your time. Maybe a better way could help us.

Comment: Maybe something like: Make it into a symbol, apply 3D rotate effect and apply clipping mask to constrain it. Then you'd double click the symbol in the symbols panel to edit the contents or with a raster image, relink it in the links panel.

Comment: Still not home but in the meantime another question with an answer you can benefit from was asked and answered. Take a look at the **perspective grid** http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67883/48529

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Symbols in Illustrator are a close equivalent to Smart Objects in Photoshop.

Drag your image to the **Symbol Panel** to create a **Symbol**.

Then use the **Symbol**. Transform the symbol however you need it. (In fact, art *must* be a symbol to apply it in Illustrator 3D effect surface mapping.)

If you then need to edit the original image later.... **Double-click the Symbol** in the **Symbol Panel**. It opens as a flat image which can be edited, added to, etc.

It is sometimes helpful to draw a no-fill/no-stroke rectangle around the artwork before making a symbol if the art is non-rectangular in nature. This creates a bounding area that, when you later edit, you need to stay within. If you edit and exceed the original bounding area, it can throw off your transformations.

Answer (score 2):

Create a box that matches the edges of the "perspective" object (directly on top of it). Select it and shift-select the picture, select the Object menu, select Envelope Distort, then Make with Top Object. This is a non-destructive method and works well for things like computer/cell phone screens.

Comment: and what about 3D cube or something like that? I need a general method. ;)